# Is there a way to generate correlated variable array from an existing array in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, pearson-correlation

I found existing methods using *np.random.multivariate_*normal function to generate 2 or more array of variables correlated to each other using covariance/coefficient value.

However, I already have an existing array lets say x1 that is available. Now I want to generate another variable x2 that would be correlated to x1 with specified pearson correlated value (e.g. 0.5).

Is it possible to do in Python?

Thanks.

Comment: It does almost what I want... except the generated array contains negative value. Is it possible to generate only positive values?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention anything about that, but if it's a requirement then you can just add some fixed amount so that all of the elements are positive; this won't change the correlation coefficient.

Comment: Ah, excellent. That would work. Thank you.